# Retry connection not attempted for span exporter

Tags: open-telemetry

We are using OpenTelemetry java api and OpenTelemetry auto configuration. If span exporter  is down then i want do retry or catch below exception.
SEVERE: Failed to export spans. Server is UNAVAILABLE. Make sure your collector is running and reachable from this network. Full error message:UNAVAILABLE: io exception

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the collector instance running and reachable from the application host where the java instrumentation exporter is running. The OTLP exporter already has a retry mechanism for transient errors as dictated by the [opentelemetry-specification](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/protocol/exporter.md#retry). In your case the collector is not even reachable. These examples might help you https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/examples.